# Как в название переменной, добавить значение другой переменной?

Tags: c++, переменные

У меня есть код:

```
int i = 12;

int hello = 4;
```

Нужно при создании в название **`2`** переменной добавить значение переменной **`i`**.

```
(int hello + i = 4 
 == int hello12 = 4)
```

Надеюсь понятно.

int i = 0;

```
while (true) {
    i++;
    int XD + i = 0; // + помечается ошибкой. Как это исправить? Хочу создать много переменных с разным названием.
}
```

Comment: Совершенно непонятно... значение `i` вы вычисляете во время работы программы? При этом (при работе программы) никаких *имен* переменных нет. Может, вам массивы нужны?

Comment: int i = 0;

 while (true) {
  i++;
  int XD + i = int XD0 потом XD1 и тд
 }

Comment: Вот теперь вообще ничего не понятно... Попробуйте спросить, не какой рукой микроскоп держать, а как забивать гвозди — чего вы хотите добиться таким образом? В чем исходная задача?

Comment: Я обновил вопрос

Comment: Имена переменных можно генерировать только в compile-time   а не во время выполнения (не в цикле). Используйте массвы или другие контейнеры, например std::map.

Comment: `Хочу создать много переменных`  - массивы, векторы, списки, словари?

Comment: int с разным названием и содержимым.

Comment: Я новичок в C++ так что мне все эти слова не знакомы

Comment: Ну начните с массива

Comment: Во-первых, все ваши переменные в цикле там и умрут, за пределами цикла они не видны. Во-вторых, как я уже писал, во время работы программы нет никаких имен переменных. В-третьих, вам таки нужно почитать о массивах...

Comment: Спасибо, я все понял)

Comment: Это: «Как в название переменной» всё?